# Develop a WYSIWYG editor in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Could anyone help me out with any sources as to how should I proceed in order to develop a WYSIWYG editor as eclipse plugin.

Thanks & Best Regards,

Ravish.

Comment: You want to develop a plugin for Eclipse? or you are looking for a plugin to help you develop?

Comment: I am looking forward to develop such plugin. I am able o make simple stuff using JFace and eclipse toolkit. However I don't have any idea how to proceed for something like WYSIWYG editor.
Any sources would really helpful

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for is [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). Here's a good, albeit old [example of using GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-diagram-editor/shape.html), and here's the [programmer's guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv/guide/guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

A WYSIWYG editor for what? For HTML, then there are the Eclipse [Webtools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) which has a WYSIWYG editor. You could take a look at their sources.

Comment: No, I have simple predefined containers and elements for which I want to have a WYSIWYG editor. Any tutorial, link to website or reference to a book is what I'm looking forward to.

Thanks