# Want to develop a WYSIWYG editor for GUI in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mobile-application, eclipse-gef

I want to develop a WYSIWYG editor for developing Mobile Apps (Hybrid). Looked into the following link. [Develop a WYSIWYG editor in eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884146/develop-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-eclipse-plugin)

I have read about GEF. But some of my friends told me that GEF is outdated and there are some alternative frameworks coming up. I couldn't find any such framework.

Kindly let me know whether GEF is the best bet or is there any other framework which I can use to develop screens for Mobile Apps

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searching about a year+ ago (see [here](http://www.vainolo.com/2011/05/24/the-quest-for-the-perfect-java-graph-framework/)), and GEF came out as the best choice. If there are other frameworks out there that I don't know of, please ask your friends to tell, but from my knowledge there aren't many. GEF is VERY complex, but at the same time provides the best abstraction to develop editors, with a lot of built-in capabilities. There is also a plan for GEF4, but that is long range.

In short, ask your friends for concrete examples, and if they can't provide you good ones, go with GEF. The future is always more promising than the present because it is not yet here :-)

Comment: Grahiti is one of them said by my friend. Your blog provides a lot of input. Thanks for the answer. I am doing some analysis on Graphiti and then will decide on it.

Comment: I tried Graphiti also. Maybe it has improved since then. If so, please tell :-).

Comment: Graphiti is also good. The advantage with Graphiti is I dont have to know abt GEF or Draw2D. I feel it is better to use GEF it has lot of capabilities